# Visual Studio 2010 Macro to Create folders in a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, itemtemplate, visual-studio-macros, project-template

We have a big C# project in Visual Studio with multiple applications under it. Developers add their application in the project by creating folders manually. I was wondering if we can automate this using templates or macro. I guess adding folders and items under it is difficult. I was thinking about macros or something else?

Is there a way to create folders automatically under an existing C# project in VS 2010? I was thinking if we can provide the macro to the developers of that C# project to run it to create folders for their application.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to "add a new application" as a subfolder to a project. I smell a rat. A whole family of them actually.

Comment: Creating a new project automatically also creates the folder for it, as specified in the dialog. Hard to see the point in automating that.

Comment: Ok, I know it smells rat and I smelt it too :) and it is no good. But I have to work on what they have from years. How about I say we have a C# project (middle tier) that has some folders like 'Orders', 'Products', etc and each has subfolders 'Data', 'Model', etc under it. I don't want to create them manually. I want to create this structure for new folders in visual studio using macro (may be).

Answer (score 0):

Believe you're talking about Visual Studio Project Templates:

- [Creating Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Create Reusable Project And Item Templates For Your Development Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx)
- [Creating your own Visual Studio Project Template](http://www.carlosag.net/articles/create-vs-template)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://studioshell.codeplex.com/ This exposes the dte extensibility model to powershell.